# How to place amCharts maps valueLegend in other div

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible to place a map valueLegend in a other div? Or how can I pass the map area data to a legend and get the same color range?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. This is very off topic without any effort or code shown - for example consult the documentation: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/putting-a-legend-outside-the-chart-area/

Comment: I need the map valueLegend outside the map div. I don't want to create a new separate legend with own data.

Comment: Please update your question with expected output so we can reopen